# How can I generate dashboard from two csv files in Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to generate a single dashboard from two CSV files. These two CSV files are generated from two different runs.

This is what I tried so far.
Merge the contents of two CSV files and prepare a final CSV file. Then, generate a Dashboard from final CSV file. But by doing this, the dashboard does not show dates of each run and hence no way to differentiate the results.

Can someone help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is currently supported, the easiest way of comparing 2 results from different test runs is using [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool

[image: JMeter Merge Results Tool Output]

This way you can get an delta overview of the response times for the same sampler for different test runs.

You can install Merge Results tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager install Merge Results]

Comment: I have tried Merge Results tool. But as mentioned in the question, if final CSV file has dates from two different runs, it is not showing dates in the graphs and hence not able to differentiate the results.

Comment: Let us take an example, if CSV1 and CSV2 are both generated on the same day then the dashboard created from final CSV file is understandable with 24hours time displayed in "Over time" graphs. But if CSV1 and CSV2 are generated on two different dates, how to show the dates in "Over time" graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the CSV files as mentioned in the above answer and add the dates in the Prefix label field in the Merge Results. So you can differentiate between them by looking at the Prefix label at least in the graphs.

[image]